# Change font of add_nodes in networkx - python

Tags: python, networkx

How to change font of nodes created using network add_nodes ?

Code :

```
g=nx.Graph()
g=nx.Graph()
node=0
for i in range(len(newinput)):
    for j in range(0,len(newinput[i])):
        g.add_node(node,size=1,pos=(newinput[i][j][0],newinput[i][j][1]))
        node+=1

    pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
    pos = nx.get_node_attributes(g, 'pos')

conn=0
while conn<node-1:
    g.add_edge(conn, conn + 1)
    conn+=1
nx.draw(g,pos)
pylab.show()
```

[image]

I don't want end points of line shown with big red circles as in above image.

I checked size=1 attribute in add_node but its not working.

Comment: 2 questions: 1)Can you show what `newinput` is? It would be convenient to play with code with data as well (so that people won't have to generate data themselves).  2) And do you just want to display the edges without the vertices or do you mean to draw vertices with a different shape and color?

Comment: @Tuan333: newinput is list[list[]] that has x and y coordinates. And Want to display only edges with nodes.
I am able to do that :) using - `nx.draw(g,pos,node_size=0.5)` will submit it as answer. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this with node_size attribute in draw function.

`nx.draw(g,pos,node_size=0.5)`

Code :

```
g=nx.Graph()
node=0
for i in range(len(newinput)):
    for j in range(0,len(newinput[i])):
        g.add_node(node,size=1,pos=(newinput[i][j][0],newinput[i][j][1]))
        node+=1

    pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
    pos = nx.get_node_attributes(g, 'pos')

conn=0
while conn<node-1:
    g.add_edge(conn, conn + 1)
    conn+=1
nx.draw(g,pos,node_size=0.5)
pylab.show()
```

New Output :
[image]